# Printing long lines in scratch buffer

Tags: string, performance, emacs, read-eval-print-loop

When evaluating a long list in the scratch buffer, eg. `load-history` with <kbd>C-u 0</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> (to see the whole output), emacs essentially freezes up trying to deal with the long lines of output.

Is there a way to force the printed output to be truncated to a set column width, so emacs can handle it easily?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you don't try to pretty-print it? E.g., if you just do `C-h v load-history`? Do you have `visual-line-mode turned on`? (If so, try turning it off.)

Comment: @Drew `visual-line-mode` is off, `C-j` is default `eval-print-last-sexp` which doesn't pretty-print.  I see this with just emacs defaults (emacs -Q) with long lines (title should be long lines not long strings) - emacs handling of long lines is just very slow in general.  You're right `C-h v` is fast since it does use pretty printing, so doesn't have long lines.

Comment: Maybe you should report this? `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `pp-eval-last-sexp` to pretty-print the value formats it more kindly, and quickly.  Use a prefix argument if you want the results in the original buffer; otherwise it outputs to a separate buffer.

Interestingly, for me this is notably faster than using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>.  The latter also pretty-prints the value, but it seems to take a similar amount of time to display it as `eval-print-last-sexp`, which suggests it may be subject to the same source of slowness before reformatting the buffer contents?

Comment: thanks, yea that is much better formatting.  They both essentially do the same thing, `C-h v` just runs a bit more code.  I was hoping for a general setting that would truncate long lines, but I don't think it exists.